# Listing php functions at the top of the file? (or, how to quickly jump to php functions?)

Tags: php, phpstorm

The php editor I use jumps to functions when I middle click their names, so I was thinking that it would be awesome if I could list all of the functions at the top of a file so that when I open the file I can quickly jump to the one I'm interested in. Of course, if I put the function names at the top of the file, then they will all be called when the file is loaded (actually, this is a class I'm talking about).

Is there any way to do this, or am I just dreaming? :-)

Comment: Why not put all your functions/class in a separate file and include it?

Comment: The file has a php class in it. The class has a few dozen long functions and so it's really annoying to have to scroll up and down trying to find the one I'm interested in when I open the file.

Comment: Sounds like you need an editor with collapsible code blocks.

Comment: @Asad - I do that a lot.. A secondary motivation for my question was that I have all of the function names at the top of the file as comments provide a kind of roadmap for what is in the class. This is probably more of a phpStorm question than a php question..

Comment: as a hacky solution, would it work for you to put all the functions up there commented then uncomment and jump?

Comment: If all functions are inside the same file where you are -- just use **Structure panel**. Otherwise -- see an answer from @Eric -- **Navigate | Symbol...** (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N)

Comment: @LazyOne - that is perfect! Thanks! Would you care to make your comment and answer?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If all functions are *inside the same file* where you are -- just use **Structure panel** (<kbd>Alt + 7</kbd>).

Alternatively use **Navigate | File Structure** (<kbd>Ctrl + F12</kbd>) which is quite similar to Structure panel (some people find this more convenient (more keyboard oriented) + it can list more elements depending on language etc).

Otherwise -- see an answer from @Eric -- **Navigate | Symbol...** (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + N</kbd>)

Comment: This also applies to JetBrains Webstorm.

Answer (score 5):

It might be too late but in PhpStorm latest version you can press Command + F12 in MacOSX or Ctrl + F12 to show the list of functions and file structures.

Answer (score 3):

[Your IDE can already do this.](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html) No need to add redundant headers to your source code:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: that looks about right, but i think he is looking for a way to jump between methods

Comment: In netbeans, I normally go with Ctrl + F to search file, and ctrl + shift + F to search the whole project for an element. When I checked now, even netbeans has this. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about literally 'listing' them or creating them at the top of the file?

```
function oneofthem() {
 // blah
}
```

or

```
oneofthem();
```

The latter of the two will load them. The first one will not load it, and is completely ok the list at the top of the file. Mind you it would obviously need to be below your class selector.

Secondly if you're just listing them -- you can always just comment them out.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scuzzy suggested, use the [code folds](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/code-folding-2.html) feature of your IDE. Keep the functions collapsed, so that they will be presented like a list.